# bind kendo ui data source to normalized data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

how do you bind Data Source to normalized data?  I know I can take the fields and data2 arrays and construct something that looks like data1 but that will be time consuming for large amounts of data.

```
// Denormalized
var data1 = [{"name":"John", "age":20},{"name":"Tom", "age":25}];

// Normalized
var fields = ["name","age"];
var data2 = [["John",20],["Tom",25]];
```

Comment: What model does the data source have?

Comment: I wasn't using a model. Should I define a model to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Not sure, but certainly all the examples I've seen of using Kendo DataSources define a model. But more a case of wanting to know how the consumer of the data is going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed mapping large amount of data manually will be time consuming, there no way to map the Kendo Grid Data Source directly to normalize data.

However if the data source of the grid is being paginated in the server, the time to process each page of data will not a mayor issue. If that's not the case you can use some library to help you with that process, I use [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) in a similar case without any issues.

For your particular sample you it will look like this:

```
var fields = ["name","age"];
var data2 = [["John",20],["Tom",25]];
var dest = []
data2.forEach(function(e,i){
    var obj = {};
    e.forEach(function(o,i){
       obj[fields[i]]=o;
    });
    dest.push(obj);
});
```

In which the `dest` array will hold the denormalized data.

Comment: thank you for your answer! that is unfortunate because I'm sending my data across the wire normalized (reducing the size of the data). to go from fields and data2 to an array that looks like data1 requires nested for loops

Comment: Do you have sample set of data? Maybe we can come to low complexity solution.

Comment: how would you go from the normalized arrays to the denormalized one?